# Graphql subscriptions with rebing/graphql-laravel

Tags: graphql, laravel-10

Are there any way to implement graphql **subscriptions** with rebing/graphql-laravel?

or a package which make it in addition to rebing/graphql-laravel.

I cannot use **rebing/graphql-laravel** with **nuwave/lighthouse** because are there many conflicts. I have make all mutations, queries and types with rebing/graphql-laravel, so it is quite difficult to remove and make it again with nuwave/lighthouse.